# Vector of static arrays with size determined at run-time

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I want a member of my class to be a vector of `std:array`, but I want the array size to be determined by a variable passed in by the user of the class. Is this possible? I attempted to do so with an initializer list, but I get the very obvious error message:

```
csvParser.cpp:18:35: error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘Parser::featureCount’ std::vector<std::array<lDouble, featureCount> > data;
```

Here's my attempt:

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>

typedef long double lDouble;

class Parser {
    const size_t featureCount;
    std::vector<std::array<lDouble, featureCount> > data;
    public:
        Parser(size_t numFeatures) : featureCount(numFeatures) {}
 };
```

NOTE: If possible, I would like for the user of the class to be able to pass in the value to determine the size of the array, but my attempt is not an indication of how anything *has* to be done, and I am open to any suggestions.

Comment: ill be short, size of std::array should be compile time value

Comment: on the other hand, if you are willing to use nested containers, why dont you settle on vector of vectors?

Comment: Suppose that `sizeof(std::vector<T>)` varies with the `sizeof(T)`. (It almost certainly doesn't, but no rule prohibits it.) What would `sizeof(Parser)` be if you were allowed to do this?

Comment: @OlegBogdanov Thanks for the input. Vector of vectors is definitely an option. I think I got hung up on vector of arrays because I felt like I was doing the "right" thing trying to use a static array since it should be a known value by the user, and each array within the vector should be the same length.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Would this imply that `sizeof(Parser)` varies with `sizeof(T)` as well? I'm not sure what you're getting at, but that doesn't mean I'm not interested and willing to play along :) (something to do with a template?)

Comment: That would mean that `sizeof(Parser)` would be incoherent since its size would vary depending on the type that `data` wound up being. In fact, it shows that `Parser` isn't a fully-specified type since the type of one of its data members is unknown.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz makes sense and the point illustrated will be beneficial to me in the future as well.

Comment: Sounds like what you want is a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T[]>>`

Comment: "array with runtime size, but size will not change after initialization" is a use case that the standard container library doesn't cover! People normally just use vector, but that does waste some resource that is not necessary for this use case.

Comment: @M.M Exactly why I was asking. I would like to use the minimum number of resources and/or the fastest implementation.

@NathanOliver thanks, I'm unfamiliar with `std::unique:ptr`, but it appears so far to be in line with what I want

Comment: @Cliff `unique_ptr` has no overhead, but it doesn't store the length of the allocation (so you may need an additional variable to hold the length)

Answer (score -1):

std::array is implemented using a C-Style Array. That's why you can not determine the size at runtime.
If you need an array that changes size at runtime, use std::vector, or use the following method.

```
class Parser
{
private:
    size_t size;
    std::vector<lDouble*> data;

public:
    Parser(const size_t& size)
        : size(size)
    {
        lDouble* arr = new lDouble[size];
        data.push_back(arr);
    }
};
```

Comment: Eww.  Manual memory management with a vector?!?  You would be better off with a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T[]>>`